# What was the meaning of line "In Moonlight Black Boys Look Blue"

Tags: moonlight

I was watching the movie Moonlight and I did not get the meaning of "In Moonlight Black Boys Look Blue". What does it mean with respect to the movie?

Comment: That's the name of the play that the film was based on.

Comment: @DrRDizzle The question still stands, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I think it depends on your interpretation of it. To me when I heard the line, then watched the whole film, I thought Moonlight was the love and we look blue because our true selves are revealed in love. Chiron was a vulnerable boy throughout the film, but towards the end he put on this Ganster facade, a false exterior. However, when Chiron reunited with Kevin, he revealed his true interior to him because he loved him. Love is the moonlight and we look blue because the moonlight, the love shows us who we really are. In moonlight black boys look blue.